# Add sorting capabilities to table in JSP

Tags: java, jsp

Is there a way to make a table in JSP sortable?

I couldn't find anything on the net regarding this, so I assume it's impossible, but I thought I would try here.

Comment: May I know which table you are talking about ??HTML table ?? or database Table ?

Comment: How are you populating your table? I guess from some container, like array or collection. If yes, then why are you trying to do sorting in JSP. You should sort the array or list in the Servlet itself, before sending it to JSP. Moreover, some more details into this question would be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this piece of [code](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/sorttable.js) for adding sorting capabilities to your tables in JSP. You would just need to include this JavaScript file to your jsp page and follow the instructions.

It is simple to implement and is under  X11 licence, which basically means you can do what you want with it, including using it at work, in a commercial setting or product, or in open source projects.

[Click here for more details](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/)

Hope this helps !!

Thanks to Stuart Langridge !!!

Answer (score 1):

[DisplayTag](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/) is a nice library that can handle that kind of stuff for you, and also includes some other neat functionalities like sorting and data export.

[Installing](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/11/install.html) the library only consists in dropping a few jars. After display tag is ready, making a sortable table is done through some custom tags provided by the library. This sample code is from [DisplayTag documentation](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/11/tut_externalSortAndPage.html):

```
<display:table name="testList" sort="external" defaultsort="1" id="element">
  <display:column property="id" title="ID" sortable="true" sortName="id" />
  <display:column property="firstName" sortable="true" sortName="firstName" title="First Name" />
  <display:column property="lastName" sortable="true" sortName="lastName" title="Last Name" />
  <display:column property="address" sortable="true" sortName="address" title="Email Address"/>
</display:table>
```